# Return an array as result of jquery ajax function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, jquery, json.net

I want to return an array from controller to view by ajax call,
and my array is a generic array (a list of objects such as an instance of `Employee` class).

I want loop on result and have access to objects property such as `Name`,
and I do not know, how can I return generic array for result from C# action (json or ...) ,

What is the return type of action?

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("EditDayRequest", "Message")',
type: 'Post',
cache: false,
data: { IsChecked: $(this).is(':checked')},
success: function (result) {
// i want to loop here on returned array and get values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Customer ViewModel looks like this

```
public class CustomerVM
{
   public string Name { set;get;}
   public string JobTitle { set;get;}
}
```

You can return Json from your Action method using the `Json` method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditDayRequest()
{
  var customerArray=GetCustomerArrayFromSomewhere();
  return Json(new { Items=customerArray.ToList()});
}
```

And in your success callback, you can loop thru the Items

```
success:function(result){
   $.each(result.Items,function(index,item){
       alert(item.Name);
       alert(item.JobTitle);
   });

}
```